# CentOS 7: Error with SSL without having any SSL certificate installed

Tags: curl, ssl-certificate, centos7, yum

I started an SSL activation process with a certificate I bought in namecheap and I followed this guide https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-self-signed-ssl-certificate-for-nginx-on-centos-7

But I stop the process since the activation took a long time and never worked and the SSL was removed and refunded from namecheap, so I removed the cerficates I created in /etc/ssl also I cleaned my nginx block with the original configuration for my website.

But now with every call using yum or composer or any external call from my website/server is displaying errors related to some missing certificates or errors with them, like these:

**With yum**

- Cannot retrieve metalink for repository: epel/x86_64. Please verify its path and try again
- https://rpm.nodesource.com/pub_6.x/el/7/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] curl#77 - "Problem with the SSL CA cert (path? access rights?)"

**With composer**

- [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]
  The "https://getcomposer.org/versions" file could not be downloaded: SSL operation failed wit
  h code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
  error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
  Failed to enable crypto
  failed to open stream: operation failed

**With a service that call to mailgun from my API**

- RequestException in CurlFactory.php line 187: cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)

Do you have any idea? Because I researched a lot and cannot find the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you've removed not only your certificates, but the bundle of CA root certificates that came with your operating system, and which all of the SSL *clients* on your system use to verify the certificates of the SSL-enabled servers they need to talk to.

On my nearby CentOS 6 box, the CA bundle is `/etc/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt`, and is from the `ca-certificates` package. I believe those are the same in CentOS 7. You can check for missing files with `rpm -V ca-certificates`, which

If that's the case and you've accidentally removed your CA bundle, you can restore it with

```
rpm -Uvh --replacepkgs http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/updates/x86_64/Packages/ca-certificates-2017.2.11-70.1.el7_3.noarch.rpm
```

which will (re-)install the package that contains the CA bundle.

Comment: You are awesome, thank you for the explanation and for the solution  :)

I have one more quick question, do you think the certificates were replaced when I followed the guide from digitalocean and when in one of the steps is telling that I should create a folder in /etc/ssl/private ?

Comment: @SoldierCorp Their guide puts the private key in a separate directory from the certificates, you can do that or you can keep everything in one directory. That said, those instructions are for a self-signed certificate -- you might be better off with [How To Install an SSL Certificate from a Commercial Certificate Authority](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-an-ssl-certificate-from-a-commercial-certificate-authority).

Comment: @SoldierCorp For that matter, now that I see you've got a refund for that Namecheap cert,, you might want to just use [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org), which offers free SSL certificates and tooling to automatically renew them.

Comment: Yes, I'm going to try with them.