# YUM Error cannot open rpm. Skipping + PiP Error - SSL CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED

Tags: python, pip, centos, ssl-certificate, yum

So I have a strange scenario here and I was wondering if someone who has more knowledge in Centos could help me here.

So I am deploying some rpm that I am trying to install to a centos server (This Centos 7 was recently installed and nothing has been added or changed). I used a Centos 7 DVD-iso image and I have used the same USB stick to deploy other CentOS 7 servers:

Let's say I have 3 Servers all with Centos:
Host1
Host2
Host3

I have tried to run the following command: `yum install -y "http://elrepo.org/elrepo-release-7.0-4.el7.elrepo.noarch.rpm"`  on all Hosts. All happy days when I run the command on HOST1 and HOST3, however, when I run the same command on HOST2 I get the following error

```
#yum install -y "http://elrepo.org/elrepo-release-7.0-4.el7.elrepo.noarch.rpm"
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Cannot open: http://elrepo.org/elrepo-release-7.0-4.el7.elrepo.noarch.rpm. Skipping.
```

I've installed all HOST servers at the same time and all of them were installed with the same iso image. I have connection to the internet, DNS works fine on all HOSTS and there is not firewall blocking traffic from HOST2.

Additionally, I was able to install on HOST2 'elrepo' rpm by other methods and then I needed to install PiP packages. When I run the PiP install on HOSTS1 and HOST3) it worked; however, on HOST2 I got a Python pip install connection error `SSL CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED` certificate verify failed.

I reinstalled my Centos7 on HOST2 thinking that there was corruption on SSL certificates and yet the problem remained. I also saw the post from another user [CentOS 7: Error with SSL without having any SSL certificate installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43948498/centos-7-error-with-ssl-without-having-any-ssl-certificate-installed) and I tried to apply to reinstall the CA-Certificates for Centos7 using this command:

```
# rpm -Uvh --replacepkgs  http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/updates/x86_64/Packages/ca-certificates-2021.2.50-72.el7_9.noarch.rpm
Retrieving http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/updates/x86_64/Packages/ca-certificates-2021.2.50-72.el7_9.noarch.rpm
warning: /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.h38Uj9: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID f4a80eb5: NOKEY
Preparing...                          ################################# [100%]
Updating / installing...
   1:ca-certificates-2021.2.50-72.el7_################################# [ 50%]
Cleaning up / removing...
   2:ca-certificates-2020.2.41-70.0.el################################# [100%]
```

and the problem was not solved...

I am out of options and I cannot get my head around why this is happening on this specific HOST. Nothing is different from HOST1 to HOST2. Could anyone please give me a hand? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So turns out that all these SSL and CA-Certificate errors were caused due to a time sync problem. when I did `date` on my Server, this was the output:

```
#date
Sat Aug  9 10:35:11 AEST 2014
```

When I updated the time/date for my server then everything works:

```
yum install -y "http://elrepo.org/elrepo-release-7.0-4.el7.elrepo.noarch.rpm"
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
elrepo-release-7.0-4.el7.elrepo.noarch.rpm                                       | 8.5 kB  00:00:00
Examining /var/tmp/yum-root-Zayovq/elrepo-release-7.0-4.el7.elrepo.noarch.rpm: elrepo-release-7.0-4.el7.elrepo.noarch
Marking /var/tmp/yum-root-Zayovq/elrepo-release-7.0-4.el7.elrepo.noarch.rpm to be installed
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package elrepo-release.noarch 0:7.0-4.el7.elrepo will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
base/7/x86_64                                                                    | 3.6 kB  00:00:00
extras/7/x86_64                                                                  | 2.9 kB  00:00:00
updates/7/x86_64                                                                 | 2.9 kB  00:00:00

Dependencies Resolved

========================================================================================================
 Package            Arch       Version                Repository                                   Size
========================================================================================================
Installing:
 elrepo-release     noarch     7.0-4.el7.elrepo       /elrepo-release-7.0-4.el7.elrepo.noarch     5.0 k

Transaction Summary
========================================================================================================
Install  1 Package
```

If someone is having a similar issue, just check your date, seems simple that that was the solution for my problem...